# How to compare values in two columns?

Tags: google-sheets

If I have the following two columns with values:

```
A    B

2    3
4    1
7    10
8    1
9    5
```

How do I create a count for column B that shows values greater than the same row in column A?

In this case, the count will be 2.

I have columns C/D and E/F that will do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(A1:A5<B1:B5))`

Assuming your data starts in cell A1.